# Trying to make Shell-Script to remove suspended accounts from WHM

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have Linux hosting server with centOS, which have WHM installed on it. To reduce the costing and mis-usage of Disk space i am creating a shell-script which automatically removes the suspended accounts which are suspended for more than 30 days and still using space on server.

Script:

```
root@ping [~]# cat autoterminate.sh
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
#!/bin/bash

find /var/cpanel/suspended/ -mtime +30 > autoterminate.txt

cut -d '/' -f5 /root/autoterminate.txt
echo "Users to remove"

cut -d '/' -f5 /root/autoterminate.txt > auto.txt

for i in `cat /root/auto.txt`; do /scripts/removeacct -y $i; done
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

When i run this script it is asking for yes or no response from my side.

```
root@ping [~]# ./autoterminate.sh

swicsor    #this is the user which i found suspended more than 30 days

Users to remove
Unknown option: y
Are you sure you want to remove the account "swicsor", and DNS zone files for the user? [y/N]?
```

Basically i want this script to run in cronjob, but i am unable to do it, as it is asking manual response of "Yes" or "No". I will be great if anyone there can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for i in `cat /root/auto.txt`; do echo "y" | /scripts/removeacct -y $i; done
```